# Electron & ES6 how to implement require remote/ipc when using gulp and ES6 modules

Tags: ecmascript-6, electron, vue.js

i am using ES6 js files that are then compiled by gulp (browserify/babel), example of a ES6 file is:

I have a normal App.js that is used to set up the main window etc.. Then the html pages will use a main.min.js file that is basically made up with all my ES6 classes compiled into one file:

loader.es6 file

```
import Main from  './pages/Main.es6'

new Main()
```

Main.es6 file

```
 import Vue from 'vue';

export default class Main extends Vue{
   constructor() {...}
   .....
}
```

When compiled and run this all works fine and all is good... But as i thought if i want to implement the 'IPC', 'Remote' modules, i am having issues with compiling as they cannot find those modules, either through the `require()` or  `import..` methods within my classes.

so doing the following fails:

```
 import Remote from 'remote'
 import Main from  './pages/Main.es6'

 new Main()
```

or

```
var Remote = require('remote')
import Main from  './pages/Main.es6'

new Main()
```

Is this possible to do or achieve, or nope needs more thought and going back to normal js please.

Any ideas / advice would be great thanks

EDIT: add the error details

An example file in question [Main.es6](https://github.com/simondavies/electron-vuejs-starter/blob/develop/resources/js/pages/Main.es6)

see the added var `var Remote = require('remote')`at the top this causes the following error.

even using `import Remote from 'remote'`

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'remote' from '/Volumes/DAVIES/ElectronApps/electron-vuejs-starter/resources/js/pages']
 stream:
  { _readableState:
  { highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: [Object],
    pipesCount: 1,
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    resumeScheduled: false },
   readable: true,
   domain: null,
   _events:
  { end: [Object],
    error: [Object],
    data: [Function: ondata],
    _mutate: [Object] },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState:
   { highWaterMark: 16,
    objectMode: true,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: true,
    ended: true,
    finished: true,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [],
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: true,
    errorEmitted: false },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _options: { objectMode: true },
  _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
   _streams: [ [Object] ],
  length: 1,
   label: 'deps' } }
```

Comment: *How* does it fail? What does the export syntax of that `remote` module look like? Please point us to the exact files (if you have to link them) instead of your entire project.

Comment: So where is that `remote` module located? Did you mean `./remote`?

Comment: its part (i believe) of the electron-prebuilt module set up. Ass running it in native js files as it all would work... it enables you to access the main electron process and modules like `var ipc = remote.require('ipc)`, it might be its not possible as of yet, so will have to use normall ES5 ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well been playing and I have managed to get this to work in a way:

Basically i set the remote and ipc modules within the html page, then pass in those, into my class for that page.

[main.html](https://github.com/simondavies/electron-vuejs-starter/blob/notification/app/pages/main.html)

```
 <script>
   var remote = require('remote');
   var ipc = require('ipc');
   new Main(ipc);
 </script>
```

[Main.js - Class File](https://github.com/simondavies/electron-vuejs-starter/blob/notification/resources/js/pages/Main.js)

```
 export default class Main extends Vue{
  constructor(ipc) {
   ....
   ipc.send('listener here','message here');

   .....
```

The files can be viewed within this [Branch](https://github.com/simondavies/electron-vuejs-starter/tree/notification):

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I'm using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) with [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify), if I tried:

`var remote = require('remote')`

I would got error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'remote' from xxx

But if I tried

`var remote = window.require('remote')`

It works.

`import remote from 'remote'` doesn't work, seems like browserify can't find those native modules not defined in `package.json`.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, the easiest way to solve this is to not minify your binaries or use browserify. Electron already has `require` in the global scope - all you need to do is run your files through Babel to ES6 => ES5 compile them ([electron-compile](https://github.com/paulcbetts/electron-compile) makes this trivially easy too). Your `import` statement will get translated to a `require`, which Electron will automatically handle out of the box.

In general, a lot of optimization strategies that you're used to on the web like minification or concatenation are unnecessary or don't make sense in Electron, you can mostly just not do them!

Comment: thanks for the comment, agree totally, but just trying use stuff i do daily etc , i am in agreement with you in many ways especially and was exactly what i was/am going to do probably in the end., thanks again. +1